# How to filter an array using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, using-directives

```
    angular.module('harbinger').
         directive('dossierList', function () {
             return {
                 restrict:"EAC",
                 template:'<div class="Dossier-details" data-ng-repeat="d in model.dossier | filter:{status:"POI"}">'+
                '<p>'+
                '<strong>'+'Dossier ID'+'</strong>:'+
                '<small>'+'{{ d.title }}'+'</small>'+
                '</p>'+
                '</div>',
etc........
```

I want to filter the array using status ,i used `filter:{status:"POI"}`  ,but it throwing error

My json

```
  [
       {
           "id": "1",
           "status": "POI",
           "title": "West Nile virus - US",
           "dossierId": "000455"
       },
       {
           "id": "2",
           "status": "I",
           "title": "influenza",
           "dossierId": "000455"
       },
       {
           "id": "4",
           "status": "P",
           "title": "corona virus",
           "dossierId": "000455"
       }
    ]
```

Comment: May try filter:{d.status:"POI"}

Comment: i tried ,but not working

Comment: using filter:{"status":"POI"} works, http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/S2KhB/

Comment: But in my directive ,its not working

Comment: have you correctly escaped your " in your template ? In your code it seems that you have unescaped "" around POI, which leads to an error, but it's not a filtering issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will be easier here than in the comments, but your issue is just linked to an escaping problem

you can see your directive here, working : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/S2KhB/1/

the issue :

```
data-ng-repeat="d in model.dossier | filter:{status:"POI"}"
```

ou can see that you used " everywhere which was understood by you browser as

```
data-ng-repeat="d in model.dossier | filter:{status:" +another attribute ignored
```

so you had an error, the only thing I did was using escaped '

```
data-ng-repeat="d in data | filter:{status:\'POI\'}"
```

and it seems to work =)

Have fun